# JavaScript iPad iOS 5 Scale and Position

Tags: javascript, ios5, position, scale

I'm developing JavaScript/HTML/CSS based web-site running on various iPad versions.
I have a strange phenomena.

The application is displaying a centered div over a lightbox.
On orientation change the div over lightbox should again be horizontally centered.

The code I use does positioning and then scaling to the div I need to display.
I've noticed that on iOS 5 only, if I run the position function (which calculates where to position the centered div) and then the scale function the div is no longer centerd.

If on the other hand first scale and than position, all is well.

I'd be happy to get any insights to help me explain this.
The scaling factor is calculated before hand and is used in the scaling method.

Thanks in advance,

Dror